# Elixir pipes and anonymous functions

Tags: functional-programming, lambda, elixir

I recently got started with Elixir.  I'm used to F#'s pipes, and `Seq.map` and LINQ's `.Select` statements.  Things are different in Elixir, and the code I have seems very ugly.  Anon functions in anon functions.

```
defrecord FileData, name: "", date: nil
  def filedetails() do
    files = File.ls!
    datestr = fn {{year, month, day}, _time} -> "#{day}/#{month}/#{year}" end
    filedates = files |> (Stream.map &(File.stat!(&1)))
                      |> (Stream.map &(&1.ctime))
                      |> Stream.map &(datestr.(&1))


    Enum.zip(files,filedates)
      |> Enum.map fn {n,d}->FileData[name: n, date: d] end

  end
```

How should this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd need to pipe three different streams - one for every manipulation. I'd probably use one Stream to do all the manipulations together, something like:

```
filedates = files |> Stream.map &((&1 |> File.stat!).ctime |> datastr.())
```

or

```
filedates = files |> Stream.map &(File.stat!(&1).ctime |> datastr.())
```